# Rad Editor -> XML and XSLT -> HTML -> PDF (itextsharp)

Tags: regex, xml-parsing, pdf-generation, itext

I am using Rad-Editor for input, and using same HTML data to generate PDF with the help of iTextSharp DLL.

if I am copying data from Word and paste it into Rad-Editor for HTML, it gives me invalid data for example:-

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <ul>
                        <strong>
                            <li>ODS Code</li>
                        </strong>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Related Providers</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Browser can easily handle these scenario like nested tags i.e. `<UL><UL>`

And Rad-Editor filter properties are:-

```
ContentFilters="IECleanAnchors, FixEnclosingP, RemoveScripts, FixEnclosingP, EncodeScripts, MozEmStrong, ConvertFontToSpan, ConvertToXhtml, IndentHTMLContent, ConvertCharactersToEntities, PdfExportFilter, DefaultFilters"
StripFormattingOptions="MsWord,MSWordNoMargins,MSWordNoFonts,MSWordRemoveAll,Span,Css,Font,ConvertWordLists,NoneSupressCleanMessage"
```

When I am generating PDF with above mention HTML is throwing me error:- Error: Insertion of illegal Element: 15

Please someone provide me input where I am going wrong or share me example how to rectify these issues in html on runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are parsing this with? If you are parsing and then manually adding each item I think you can get this exception if you try to add an item where `el.IsContent()` returns false. Also, see the notes on the editor's site about not being 100% XHTML compliant as well as the different ways to get mostly valid XHTML. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-xhtml-compliance.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's the `<strong>` tag wrapping the `<li>` tag.  Try:

```
<li><strong>ODS Code</strong></li>.
```